# Can Amazon Redshift Autofeed INTO a Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want Amazon Redshift to push any new rows that get inserted into an Amazon Kinesis Firehose that will transform the data with a Lambda function.

Can this be done? If so, can you point me to an example and documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is **no trigger mechanism** within Amazon Redshift to cause other things to happen (either *within* Redshift or *external* to it).